# DynamoDB pagination and Go - Always exists a LastEvaluatedKey

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to paginate a query DDB and I got confused with LastEvaluatedKey.

```
func (t *...) GetAllPaginated(ctx context.Context, period string, lastId string) (..., error) {

    var lastEvaluatedKey map[string]types.AttributeValue

    if lastId != "" {
        lastEvaluatedKey = map[string]types.AttributeValue{
            "pk":      &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: ...},
            "sk":      &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: ...},
            "periodo": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{Value: ...},
        }
    }

    input := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        ...
    }

    if len(lastEvaluatedKey) > 0 {
        input.ExclusiveStartKey = lastEvaluatedKey
    }

    paginator := dynamodb.NewQueryPaginator(t.dynamodbClient, input)

    var transactions []...

    if paginator.HasMorePages() {

      page, err := paginator.NextPage(ctx)

        if err != nil {
            log...
            return ...{}, err
        }

        for _, item := range page.Items {
            ...
            transactions = append(transactions, ...)
        }

        return ...<<transactions AND LAST ID read>>... , nil

    }

    return ...{}, nil

}
```

This works fine. But since I always get an existing page, there is always a LastEvaluatedKey and I just know that there are no more pages when I make a new request to the **GetAllPaginated** method with the lastId. And then I get an empty response.

To try to change it, I changed it to:

```
func (t *...) GetAllPaginated(ctx context.Context, period string, lastId string) (..., error) {

    ...

    if paginator.HasMorePages() {

      page, err := paginator.NextPage(ctx)

        if err != nil {
            log...
            return ...{}, err
        }

        for _, item := range page.Items {
            ...
            transactions = append(transactions, ...)
        }

        paginator.NextPage(ctx)
        newLastId := ""

        if paginator.HasMorePages() {
           newLastId = transactions[len(transactions)-1].Id
        }

        return ...<<transactions AND NEW LAST ID>>... , nil

    }

    return ...{}, nil

}
```

It works perfectly fine! But I don't know how unnecessary a new call to "nextPage" can be.